# Regression with Constrained fitted value

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, constraint

I would like to fit a (generalized) linear regression model such that that the predicted values must be greater than one of the input variables.

For example...

$\hat{age} =\beta_{1}*\text{age of first steps} + \beta_{2}*\text{parents income} + \dots$

subject to:

$\hat{age} > \text{age at first step}$

(because we know that if an infant took first steps at 13 months, they must be at least 13 months old...)

My current solution is to subtract age of first step from age, fit a Poisson regression, and then afterwards add the age at first step back to the fitted value to get an estimate of $\hat{age}$

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I know there is constrained regression, but it seems that in my reading, this constrains the parameters, not the output.

Comment: Using something like censored regression is on the right track (like in this paper https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censReg/vignettes/censReg.pdf) , but this only allows for a single scalar value to be the censor, but in the above situation, each has their own unique left censor

Comment: I don't think it really makes sense to fit a Poisson to *age*; age is not a count. The idea of subtracting *age at first step* from the response and fitting a model suitable for a positive response makes sense -- just not that the resulting adjusted response would be Poisson.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica, do you think that re-framing age to be "count of days from birth" would make this make more sense? I know we can use other types of links (like gamma/exponential, as you state here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295105/poisson-regression-for-number-of-days-prediction), but does that reframing change things?

Comment: I considered the same idea myself in the past but it doesn't work; it's a discretized duration, not a count in the required sense. It doesn't have the properties that would make it work like a Poisson, nor a binomial, it's very unlikely to be much like a negative binomial (though the extra parameter means that sometimes it won't be terrible). Better to treat a duration as a duration; e.g. you're more likely to be able to identify a model with close to the right kind of mean-variance relationship. I'd consider distributions used in models for survival times, but there are other possibilities.